# How to list source code when there are both declaration and definition in LLDB?

Tags: lldb

I have some problems about source code list when there are both class/function declaration and definition. I want to go to definition, however, it always goes to declaration. What can I do for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is that:

```
(lldb) source list -n functionName
```

lists the declaration not the definition, that's a known bug.

One way to work around it is to set a breakpoint on the name, and then use the breakpoint listing to get the file & line number.  That's pretty gross but does work...

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I try to list the file by `source list -f fileName`, it also fails and asserts that `error: could not find source file "fileName"`. But for the same file, I can use `breakpoint set -f fileName -l lineNumber` to set break points. Do you know what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of a way that would happen.  If you can make this happen in a project you can share, please file a bug with the llvm.org bugzilla: http://bugs.llvm.org.